# What technology do IR temperature guns use?

Tags: sensor, temperature

I've seen contactless thermometer guns for sale for ~£40-50, which can read temperatures up to 1000°C. However, the only electronics components I can find which can measure these temperatures without contact seem to be very specialist and very expensive (>£100). The only hobby electronics level IR sensors I can find seem to be rated to either 260°C or 380°C. So what technology are the commercial 1000°C guns using inside?

Comment: Contactless means it doesn't have to touch the high temperature part. Thermocouples are cheap and are good for up to 1400 degC.

Comment: I would imagine the low-cost thermometer guns just use a IR photodiode, and you can then just relate the noise-power you get out in the right band with the temperature of your device. I believe it even increases with a quad-power law once you get into IR/optical range.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry I'm not sure I understand - I thought that thermocouples had to make contact with the object they are measuring? So these cheap thermometer guns can't use them. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JorenVaes That sounds promising, would it not be really susceptible to external conditions though, like the daylight etc.?

Comment: @rno a contactless thermometer gun can read high temperatures but it doesn't make contact so why should it have parts that are suitable for high temperatures. Are you in fact wanting to know how contactless guns work? Thermocouples do have to make contact AND the guns of course don't use them - they use a different concept altogether. Is you question about how contactless guns work?

Comment: @Andyaka I agree that the parts themselves don't need to be suitable for high temperatures because they do not make contact with the hot object. Yes, my question is about what technology the guns use to measure temperatures. The answer below by pjc50 offers a good explanation for the guns which can operate up to 380°C, but I am still unsure how the guns which operate up to 1000°C work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Are you in fact wanting to know how contactless guns work?
```

> *Yes, my question is about what technology the guns use to measure
>   temperatures.*

Consider this picture of black body spectral radiation: -

[image]

On the picture above I've drawn two vertical bands coloured orange and light blue. These bands represent the parts of the infra red spectrum where two different photodiodes might have their most sensitive region. Photodiodes can be made to have a very tight spectral sensitivity if they are used with optical filters - this is important for contactless temperature measurements because you only want to pick-up part of the spectrum so that you can adequately differentiate one temperature from another.

The orange band (circa 7 um) is good for sensing ambient temperatures and maybe up to 1000 K but the curves of black-body radiation tend to merge above this making accurate temperature measurements prone to error.

The blue band (circa 1 um) is good for higher temperatures but pretty useless for measuring anything much below 1000 K due to lack of sensitivity (aka increase noise causing errors).

Given that most commercial applications (the biggest majority of sales and applications) will use sensors in the orange band area (with a pinch of salt) they will be the cheaper technology because of much higher volume.

Given that high temperature applications won't work at ambient or moderate temperatures and they represent a much smaller quantity of sales, they will naturally tend to be more expensive.

---

### How they work

Black body radiation is light emitted from the surface of an object and not light reflected by that object - that's embedded in the term "black-body" - a black body cannot reflect, it can only emit. But real world objects are not perfect black bodies and real world objects vary in their amount of emissivity. So, life, as usual isn't perfect and we make the best job we can and use [Plank's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) to give us the best answers we can expect: -

[image]

Another name for a contactless device is an [optical pyrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrometer) in case you wanted to do some further reading.

Answer (score 5):

The magic word is "contactless". The thermometer itself does not change temperature very much. I have a cheap plastic version of one of these and have seen temperatures from -100C (pointed at clear night sky) to +250C from cooking.

The device will be built around an [Infra-red (IR) light sensor like this one](https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90614/Digital-Plug-Play-Infrared-Thermometer-TO-Can). You can see from the datasheet:

> -40°C…+125˚C for sensor temperature and  -70°C…+380˚C for object temperature

The principle of operation is the [Stefan-Boltzmann law.](https://www.omega.co.uk/technical-learning/infrared-temperature-measurement-theory-application.html) In the particular IR band used, the amount of IR light visible is almost perfectly proportional to the temperature of the object. The device then just needs to subtract its own temperature in order to determine how hot the target is.

This is the same phenomenon as "white hot" and "red hot" objects visible to the human eye, but by using the IR band we can determine temperature in a much more useful range for everyday life.

(Bonus content: a great [climate science paper by Forrest M Mims III](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/2011BAMS3215.1), the author of various tutorial books, on measuring water content of the sky using cheap IR thermometers)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think I had seen something like that one when I was searching (the MLX90614), but I only found that it goes up to +380˚C for its measuring temperature - so is this the same technology used for the guns which go up to +1000˚C? Looking at the other links you sent, I see no reason why the same physical laws would stop applying past a certain temperature, but I just haven't come across any actual sensors which say they can measure beyond the +380˚C mark

Comment: I've looked more at the datasheet for the MLX90614 that you linked, and while the output range is programmable, it's maxxed out at 382.2°C. I can't find anything similar (thermopile in a metal can) which exceeds this range, let alone gets anywhere near 1000°C (at least not for any reasonable "mass-manufacture" type cost). So I'm wondering if they use some other technology for the higher range?

Comment: Hmm. It's possible - 1000C will be well into the visible light range, at which point you need sensors in a different band. I wonder if the calibration is more of a pain too. You might get a reply if you email an inquiry to the manufacturer? Or look at the datasheet of the higher temperature ones.

Comment: (I think I oversimplified your original question, sorry)